# Console.KeyAvailable doesn't detect the key

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to make a simple snake game in console (without eating something, only snake moving around) but when I press <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>, it doesn't do anything. I also tried <kbd>W</kbd> but it writes `w` to console instead.

Code:

```
while(Console.KeyAvailable == true)
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("*");
        Console.WriteLine("*");
        Console.WriteLine("*");
        x++;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Remove both of your `Console.KeyAvailable` altogether. `ReadKey` will wait for a key press, so there is no need for the second KeyAvailable. The first one doesn’t work because when your applications starts you can’t press a key fast enough to enter your while loop so it will directly go to your ReadLine statement. Also you `WriteLine`s won’t behave like you think they do. The first will be printed at (x,y), the second at (1,y+1) because you do a line feed with carriage return which resets x to leftmost position, the third at (1,y+2) and the fourth at (x+1,y+3) – that hardly looks like a snake.

Comment: @ckuri its working now! thank you.

Comment: @ckuri I replaced WriteLine's with Writes. It moves two times but after two moves it doesnt move. I think it's because of Console.ReadLine but i'm not sure. It supposed be a drawing while arrow keys are pressed.

Comment: Use the debugger to see how your program works. If it’s going to ReadLine it means you did like in aliozgurr's answer below and you pressed a key other than UpArrow. If you want do avoid do something like `while (true) { var key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key; if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow) { … } if (key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break; }` meaning when UpArrow do your snake move up, when Escape exit the loop, otherwise ignore all other keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Console.KeyAvalible - both. Your program passes the loop and goes to ReadLine immediatly.

Should look like this:

```
while(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
{
//code here-
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try bellow code.It can be helpful for you.Don't forget to take input for x and y.

```
       while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key>0)
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                x++;
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't detect it because if a key is pressed it must be reset like so:

```css
if (Console.KeyAvailable)
{
   Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```